# iPad controller app for Pro Tools

Tags: pro-tools, ipad, controller

So I just got an iPad2 and was thinking of hooking up it with PT9 on my Mac Book Pro. Faders and knobs would be really useful for mixing many other wonderful things, as well as automation mode capabilities. Question is: Which app has the best support/best value for money for PT?

[ProRemote](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/proremote/id286627793?mt=8) - Cool but real pricey

[V-Control Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/v-control-pro/id400423823?mt=8) - Also a bit too pricey, but cheaper than ProRemote

[AC-7 Core](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/ac-7-core/id403915394?mt=8) - Was thinking of this one but not too sure, anyone used this? It's really a lot cheaper than the previous 2 but maybe some stuff's missing that the previous 2 have.

There are also nice apps for other DAWs like [TouchOSC](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/touchosc/id288120394?mt=8) and [Mrmr](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/mrmr-osc-controller/id294296343?mt=8), but PT if I'm not wrong, doesn't support OSC >:(

Any others?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually since you pointed out that V-Control again (and it now supports cubase), I've been having a chat with Paul Neyrinck, and I must say I have found him very helpful and enthusiastic about making this app as good a control surface as possible.

So as @Stavrosound pointed out, I think you are in safe hands.

The other plus point is the app you run on mac/pc side to deal with wi-fi networking is very very simple, click and play.  PC setup for wifi on some other surface apps is a bit more fiddly (can't comment on the mac side though).

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: thank you! yeah that helps a bunch, I'll try using the V-control Lite for a bit before committing

Answer (score 2):

While I have not directly used any of these, I have been intrigued by them and throw my 2 cents on for considering checking out the V-Control Pro because Neyrinck is behind it and they have a long, successful track record in the post sound world with their software offerings.  I think ProRemote is one of the first that came out, I don't know much about it, but it looks equally as enticing.

Comment: Hey! Yeah, good track record is a great point. I'll take that into consideration. Thank you ! 

Answer (score 2):

I've been using AC-7 Core with Cubase to good effect.

It just pretends to be a Mackie Control Universal, so functions like that unit.  It's a little fiddly in places as the app is a 'one screen' approach.

V-Control looks prettier and splits things into multiple panels which may be less fiddly for the smaller controls.

In both cases you need as strong a wi-fi connection as you can get, this is the Achilles' heel of this kind of solution, if the signal is not strong you get greater lag and disconnections for periods of time.

Having said that I am going to have a look at the free version of V-Control and see how it is, I may switch myself to the pro version if it feels a little more comfortable.

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the V-Control Pro since day one. Was hoping to be able to use the faders for mixing DIA but that was no success. Maybe for mixing music, but i like to watch the picture and waveforms when riding faders and thats not easy with a touch screen :)

Early next year Neyrinck will make it possible to mirror plugins on the ipad. Maybe that will
do the trick: [AES 2011 NYC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpQ7j__lv3o)